# asp.net mvc 3 double level authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

suppose i have a forms authentication in my application. once authenticated, it can access certain folders / controllers in my website

auth level 1 -> profile,history,change password

but, certain users can access another part of site if they pass level 2 . this type of users are like resellers (like sellers of accounts, etc)

auth level 2 -> sell accounts, view online users

the question is, how can i implement this another forms authentication in mvc 3 app? can these 2 form authentication coexist?  tnx

Comment: Does the user need to sign in with a different username/password in order to access this second level?

Comment: they can be the same username and password. there are just users that have level 2 skill. something like that. do u get the gist?

Comment: if it is the same username and password why reauthenticate? This user already posses the necessary roles to access  profile,history,change password and sell accounts, view online users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely you only need the one auth method.

What you are describing sounds like you want to implement "roles". I dont understand why you need 2 form authentication processes.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs
https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043732/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/082703-1.aspx

Comment: its like, there are users which have the level 2 skill, then these level2 users can access certain parts not available to level 1 (ordinary users). well, im authenticating against mysql database. (is it compatible with roles concept? or it just complicates the setup)

Comment: You should still be able to use a single form auth process but I believe it depends on the MySQL provider you use. [Read this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/mysqlmembershipprovider.aspx)